# how to find title text of a link

Tags: jquery

How do I find the title text of a link in jquery.

Comment: Or, I guess the OP is trying to get the title of the page that follows the link!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `attr` to find `title` attribute.

```
var title = jQuery("a").attr("title"); //replace "a" with your own selector
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean the text of the link:

```
var link_text = $('#someLink').text();
```

If you mean the `title` *attribute* (the text that you see when you hover over the link):

```
var link_title = $('#someLink').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 3):

You get attributes such as title for links (or any other element) like so:

```
$('a').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var title = $(this).attr("title");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the text of the title attribute of the link, you can use this, assuming that `myLink` is a jQuery object of your link:

```
myLink.attr("title")
```

However, if you mean the actual text of the link, then you can use this:

```
myLink.text()
```

You can read the jQuery documentation for the `attr` method [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) and the documentation for the `text` method [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text).