# jQuery how to get the title of link

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find title text of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025940/how-to-find-title-text-of-a-link)

How do I get the title of a link using jQuery?